# Kulback Leibler divergence between two vectors of words

Tags: probability, probability-distribution

I have two vectors of words, for ex:

```
  v1 = ["today", "rainy", "weather", "storm"]
  v2 = ["prediction", "sunny", "high", "temperature"]
```

I would like to compute the Kulback Leibler divergence between these two vectors. How can I do that in Python? Thank you!

Comment: You need to have probabilities of something to compute kl-d.

Comment: you'll need arrays of probabilities for `v1` and `v2`